# How to increase observation value by one?

Tags: matlab

I use the following code to find a specific entry in my dataset and set this value to `obsNum`:

```
originalSet(strcmp(originalSet.ABC, subset.DEF{row}) & strcmp(originalSet.FGH, task),21) = dataset(obsNum);
```

However, I would like to increase the current value by `obsNum` instead of setting it to obsNum, but I can't find a syntax for it. In Java I would simply write `+=`, but how can I do that in Matlab?

Comment: I don't fully understand your code snippet, but according to your description, is this what you want?
currentvalue=currentvalue+obsNum

Comment: Cici that is exactly what I want to achieve!

Comment: See: [What is the equivalent to += in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637735/what-is-is-the-equivalent-to-in-matlab). Matlab does not support [compound assignment operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Compound_assignment_operators).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Matlab syntax support for the `+=` operator, you'll need to index into the variable twice:

```
idx = strcmp(originalSet.ABC, subset.DEF{row}) & strcmp(originalSet.FGH, task);
originalSet(idx,21) = originalSet(idx,21) + dataset(obsNum);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm going to try this one.