# how can I do a *= operator in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm trying to do in Matlab:
X = X*-1;

this syntax is a bit annoying, is there a way to do this some other way (like in c++ : x*=-1)

Thank you

Comment: AFAIK the answer is NO !

Comment: Related (if not possibly duplicate): [What is the equivalent to += in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637735/what-is-is-the-equivalent-to-in-matlab). Matlab does not support [compound assignment operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Compound_assignment_operators).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no increment and compound assignment operators in Matlab. I also remember reading posts by employees at Mathworks saying that they don't intend to add such operators to Matlab.

Steve Lord's reply to the following question illustrates the difficulties involved (way down, reply nr 10 or so):  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/107451

Comment: The link is down, "As of December 2017 the Newsreader application has been shut down." May I know his reply?

Comment: @Unknown123 Wayback Machine has [a snapshot](http://web.archive.org/web/20150103073419/http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/107451)

Answer (score 4):

There is another way! ;-)

```
X = -X;
```

Seriously though, I think it's just a matter of habit. There's nothing inherently wrong with that syntax, you are just used to do it differently.