# Adding a Square Matrix to a Larger Square Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix (A) that is size 30x30 and I want to add it to a matrix of zeros of size 33x33 (B). I need the final matrix B to have A in the lower right corner of matrix B. How would I go about writing that into Matlab?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to *replace* the lower right part of `B`:

```
B(4:33,4:33) = A;
```

or if you really do want to *add* `A` to that part of `B`, as it says in your question title:

```
B(4:33,4:33) = B(4:33,4:33) + A;
```

Comment: Adjusted the second part to valid matlab syntax.

Comment: it looks like you posted before me with the same answer. this is the right answer

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: thanks - that's interesting - I tested this in Octave with the `+=` syntax - does MATLAB not support `+=` ?

Comment: @PaulR No, it doesn't. See the link in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637735/what-is-the-equivalent-to-in-matlab) for a discussion

Answer (score 0):

I guess you really need something like

```
B(4:33,4:33) = A;
```

Or:

```
B(4:33,4:33) = B(4:33,4:33) + A;
```

But perhaps also interesting:

```
B(end+1:end+30,end+1:end+30)=A
```

This can easily be adjusted to make for nice concatenations below or to the right.

Comment: That work if B is a 3x3 matrix of zeros. But if B is already allocate 33x33, this won't work.

Comment: @AlexandreBizeau I suppose you are looking for the middle option I just edited in.

Comment: Yes the `B(end+1:end+30,end+1:end+30)=A;`