# Updating values in an array with logical indexing with a non-constant value

Tags: arrays, matlab

A common problem I encounter when I want to write concise/readable code:

I want to update all the values of a vector matching a logical expression with a value that depends on the previous value.

For example, double all even entries:

```
weights = [10 7 4 8 3];
weights(mod(weights,2)==0) = weights(mod(weights,2)==0) * 2;
% weights = [20 7 8 16 3]
```

Is it possible to write the second line in a more concise fashion (i.e. avoiding the double use of the logical expression, something like *i+=3* for *i=i+3* in other languages). If I often use this kind of vector operation in different contexts/variables, and I have long conditionals, I feel that my code is less concise and readable than it could be.

Thanks!

Comment: See also this: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/154981

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
ind = mod(weights,2)==0;
weights(ind) = weights(ind)*2;
```

This way you avoid calculating the indices twice and it's easy to read.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is still that this is a two-liner instead of a one-liner, and if I have 30 of these operations (with different logical expressions each time), I need to write 30 two-liners, and allocate 30 temporary variables that are just used in the next line.

What I was wondering was: why is notation like
    `weights(mod(weights,2)==0) *= 2;`
not supported in Matlab, and is there a reason why this is not possible?

Edit: ok I could reuse `ind` every time so no need for 30 variables, but the point remains :)

Comment: I am sure that you can come up with some obscure routine in order to do this in only one line. However, I doubt that this can be done without internally assigning a variable, like I did in my answer. I think you just have to accept that Matlab cannot do this. Well, except nagging Mathworks really bad until they implement it ;)

Comment: What really matters in the end is not the number of SLOC but the execution time, so "stop worrying"(TM)  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Starting your other comment to Wauzl, such powerful operation capabilities is the Fortran side. This is purely matlab's design that is quickly getting obsolete. Let's use this horribleness further:

```
for i=1:length(weights),if (mod(weights(i),2)==0)weights(i)=weights(i)*2;end,end
```

It is even slightly faster than your two liner because you are doing the conditional indexing twice on both sides. In general, consider switching to Python3.

Comment: I cannot believe a `for` loop is actually faster in Matlab, but it's true, I tested it. On the other hand even for very large amounts of doing this and even for very long vectors, the time difference is very small and in my eyes negligible.

Comment: @Wauzl True. That should have been never possible but it is only in matlab. Leave the dark side and come to Python. They use the same Fortran backend. There is no added value on insisting a closed framework and a C mutant :P

Answer (score 0):

Well, I after more searching around, I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637735/what-is-the-equivalent-to-in-matlab) that deals with this issue (I used search before posting, I swear!), and there is interesting further discussion regarding this topic in the links in that thread. So apparently there are issues with ambiguity when introducing such an operator.

Looks like that is the price we have to pay in terms of syntactic limitations for having such powerful matrix operation capabilities.

Thanks a lot anyway, Wauzl!

Comment: ummmm  *what* powerful matrix ops?  SciPy and R  can do it better and faster.